# re-directing NGINX - what I'm doing has no effect

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

in my nginx condig file I'd like to make a rule so that calls to the old URL style in my site like `mysite.com/airplanes/boeing` are redirected (permanently) to `mysite.com/categories/airplanes/boeing`

`rewrite ^/airplanes/$ /categories/airplanes/ permanent;`

But calls to `mysite.com/airplanes/boeing` are still going through, hitting `404`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in regular expression. It will match exactly `/airplanes/`, so will not match `/airplanes/boeing`.

It should be

```
rewrite ^/airplanes/(.*)$ /categories/airplanes/$1 permanent;
```